# Is Stack Exchange network making business with Russians organizations nowadays?

Tags: discussion, company, business-model

Recently in some discussions in SE network I have used the argument that **likely** SE (actually, it was regarding SO and SE, but I understand that by definition if something refers to SO, then it refers to SE as well) is making money / business with Russians organizations, helping them grow, and these organizations are paying taxes, so the government has money to continue the war.

However, I don't feel really comfortable saying this and adding that it is *likely* etc. I think it is not 100% ethical. That's why I would like to know.

Comment: I don't think they can reveal their clients - but In the current environment, it probably is generally a concern

Comment: Anyhow... not sure how to say this, but the downvotes are most likely not due to your question being not good, so you can't improve it. They are being cast because people don't like questions accusing Stack Exchange of supporting "the bad guys".

Comment: Stackoverflow Teams are blocked in Russia, if that helps. We see "Sorry, this product is not accessible to you." on registration page. Not sure about jobs or other services.

Comment: Corresponding Q&A about the above with an official answer by Teresa: [How is Stack Exchange Inc dealing with current and future business with Russian entities?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377392/335251) (@JourneymanGeek: Would this post be a duplicate of the linked post by you?)

Comment: And an earlier MSO post that also supports what @MSDN.WhiteKnight says: [Why is Teams not accessible to me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411096/1478931)

Comment: I will leave someone else to determine if it's a dupe. Conflict of interest and the mod hammer and all that . Looks like it tho

Answer (score -15):

Given that computer programmers in Russia will pay taxes and work for companies that pay taxes, anything that helps a computer programmer in Russia do her/his job is giving money to Putin.

Hence can we at least have clear warnings on all questions that come from Russia?

Comment: Even if the question does not come from Russia, Russians can read answers and benefit from them... Better replace all content with anti-war propaganda for Russian IPs it that's really a concern.