# Should we switch from marking a question as opinion-based into marking an answer as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, close-reasons

I think that possibility to mark questions as opinion-based is problematic for few reasons:

1. It is just hard or impossible to predict if question is opinion based.

   - asker has to predict what other users would do (because "opinion-based" means that answers *will be* opinion-based)
   - there is no hard rules for when question will be marked as opinion-based, i.e. I have searched / asked about this (unfortunately, the question was deleted, but it was rather clear that I would not receive answer on question "what to do to make it less likely that question will be marked as opinion-based?" - It was deleted as duplicated with this one: [How to properly use 'ethics' tag to avoid closing the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416253/how-to-properly-use-ethics-tag-to-avoid-closing-the-question) and based on his answer, it is clear that it is impossible to speak about rules in the case of opinion-based mark.
2. It is unfriendly for especially new users who do not have bad intentions.

   - I remember a situation from SO when a user asked (I don't remember details) what should he use to host an R / Shiny application. And if I'm not wrong, he used the unfortunate word "Should". For me it was (taking into account the body of question) clear that he just don't know what solutions exist and he is looking for any help to at least be able to start with this topic. I tried to change this question into something like "What should I use to be able to..." to highlight the fact that he want to know any solution (technology) which can do something for him. I know that this user could do this in his own, but (1) he was a new user; (2) look at the point 1: for him feedback that "it is opinion-based" was not clear enough (the same as for me often).
3. It is difficult to reconcile with questions about ethics. I mean - in my opinion, it is easy to reconcile, but it needs additional work to rewrite the question not because (let me say that) the question is bad, but because it is not clear for a lot of people that it is about ethic.

   - As an example, I saw this question on politics site today: [Should Western governments encourage corporations to terminate remote services from Russia?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71252/should-western-governments-encourage-corporations-to-terminate-remote-services-f) with the very interesting comment (by @CJDB):

   > Questions asking whether governments should or shouldn't do something are not a good fit for this website which is focussed on objective questions and answers

   And I was thinking if it is possible to improve the question and decided to use this question title: *Is a war sufficient argument to say it is morally good to encourage corporations by Western governments to terminate remote services from Russia?* And what I want to say is that - if I'm right - only what was needed was to show *explicitly* that this is about "is X morally good taking into account context Y". It was - as I believe - not only the intention of asker, but it was also the standard question about ethic.

I would like to summarize all of this with the thesis that the **current mechanism feels injustice for askers and should make responsible for answers not asker, but responders**.

Then I would like to ask (let me use this word): **should we make the responsible party be the responders?**

We could imagine that only answers could be marked as opinion-based, i.e. when for example there are no supporting facts, citations and when we feel that this answer is based on, well, nothing. And I think that then a lot of questions (recently marked as opinion-based) could be just marked as duplicated (i.e. if the asker does not ask about specific context, i.e. not "is this code time-efficient?", but "is this code good?", then we can be almost sure that the same question was asked at least many times before and just mark it as duplicated, but leaving this very first question "is this code good" open, because it still can get valuable answers which will take into account many context and indicators). And opinion-based answers could be just deleted.

Comment: We don't currently have a mechanism for "marking" answers as anything other than simply deleting them or voting on them. (that's not to say we can't have such a thing, but you're requesting effectively an entirely new system, not a small adjustment to what we have)

Comment: *You also used the word “good” 7 times outside of a quote, hence the reason, questions seeking an opinion make really bad questions for a Q&A website.*

Comment: "*It is just hard or impossible to predict if question is opinion based.*" no, it's not. Sure, *maybe* and *in some situations* it's *harder*. But that's a far cry from hard or impossible in the general case. Does the question have a concrete factual answer? Then it's not opinion based. "How to set the colour of some element" does not call for opinions. "What colour should I choose" does. There are *some* cases where it's harder to predict but it comes from not really knowing enough about what is being asked and research can lead to a better non-opinion based question.

Comment: @VLAZ no, you are wrong. Cerbrus showed this clearly (but you can discuss with him if you want): _I already answered that in the older question: "The community votes on your question. If the majority of users deem the question to be off-topic, for whatever reason, the question will get closed."_ (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416255/how-to-properly-ask-question-about-ethic-which-less-likely-be-marked-as-opinion?noredirect=1#comment896886_416255). (he thought about opinion-based, not off-topic). He clearly stated there is no rules, just community opinion.

Comment: @gss No, you claim that POB closure is completely arbitrary. I say it is not. And the comment you point to also does not say that. Not understanding the closure is not the same as there not being any rhyme or reason and the closure being random.

Comment: @VLAZ OK, so you are saying that we can show at least one rule (as an evidence it is not arbitrary). And you did it - _Does the question have a concrete factual answer? Then it's not opinion based._. I understand this rule. And I understand this it means that this question: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71153/can-russia-be-cut-off-from-the-internet shouldn't be marked as opinion-based (see great accepted answer). Am I right?

Comment: @gss I don't see how it's *not* POB. It's asking "is it possible" not as "is it technically possible" but "would it be done". Which cannot be answered objectively - there are great many factors there. Furthermore, it asks "*would it support Putin or hurt him?*" which is not objectively answerable because *again* there are great many factors. The question is further too broad. No, I do not think it should be reopened. I think you should realign your expectation of what POB *means* instead of just trying to claim it's arbitrary.

Comment: @VLAZ, but let's focus on this: _Does the question have a concrete factual answer? Then it's not opinion based_. 21 users found the accepted answer helpful. Isn't it an evidence that _question have a concrete factual answer_? It has so many upvotes, how so helpful answer can be opinion-based?

Comment: "*Isn't it an evidence that question have a concrete factual answer?*" no, it means at least 21 users clicked the upvote button. Score does not correlate with on-topicness.

Comment: @VLAZ to be honest, I see much bigger problem with your answer (_Does the question have a concrete factual answer? Then it's not opinion based_) - often the question is closing very early, when none answers were provided (https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71252/is-a-war-sufficient-argument-to-say-it-is-morally-good-to-encourage-corporations) - how long should we wait to check if answers are (will be) based on facts?

Comment: You need to wait zero time. It's evident from the question. Hence why it's not arbitrary as you claim it is. The latest question you dug up is *also* does not have a fact-based solution. It either asks a) whether companies *will act in certain way* under *certain circumstances*. Which is about as vague as you can get in order to ask people to guess the future. And guesses are going to be opinions. or b) asks *whether* companies should act in certain way inder certain circumstances. Which...asks for opinions . Closure is not based on the answers *already there*.

Comment: @VLAZ you really don't see contradiction here?
a) _Does the question have a concrete factual answer? Then it's not opinion based_
b) _You need to wait zero time [for answers - gss]. It's evident from the question_
?

Comment: No, I do not. *You* are the one who seems to think that answers should be present in order to close a question as POB. You also seem to think that I'm contradicting myself for saying that no answers are needed to judge a question. Yet, that's not what I've ever said. In the majority of cases, a POB question can be identified without requiring answers.

Comment: @VLAZ Actually, no, my opinion is in my question above about this topic, I'm discussing about your opinion. But perhaps I get it now: do you want to say that _Does the question have a concrete factual answer? Then it's not opinion based_ OR _You need to wait zero time [for answers - gss]. It's evident from the question_?

Comment: I'm saying both of these things. You do not need to wait for answers. If a question has concrete and factual answer *which does not need be posted yet*, then it's on-topic. You do not need answers present to judge the question. You can judge what answers *will* be present. "What colour should I choose" is POB because it will not lead to a concrete and factual answer.

Comment: I think it is very, very hard to say what will be in the future and unfair to judge something based on the prediction.

Comment: One of the most sensible suggestions on Meta! I support moderation for both questions and answers, though. Answers marked as "opinion-based" could be transformed into comments by moderators, so their content would not be lost anyway.

Answer (score 4):

There are various ways already to deal with opinion-based answers:

#### Post notices

Moderators can add post notices ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366642/295232)) like this one:

> **Want to improve this post?** Add citations from reputable sources by editing the post. Posts with unsourced content may be edited or deleted.

and some sites in the network have custom ones. If nobody (the answer author or one of the other community members) improves the answer, it may be deleted. There's no automatic mechanism for this like a review queue or [Roomba](/help/roomba), so they often stick around, but the negative score and the notice serve as a clear indication that it's bad.

Some sites even have a notice on the (presumably subjective) *question* discouraging subjective *answers*: ([example](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/224448/8732); more information [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/hard-science/info)).

#### Back it up

Some sites which intrinsically deal with subjective questions like The Workplace, Parenting and Interpersonal Skills have a [Back it up](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/33983) rule. You can't just post your opinion and deem it to be a good answer; you have to provide evidence. Answers which don't comply are often flagged as low quality and deleted.

#### Flags

If you see an answer which is nothing more than a rant, you can flag it as very low quality or (especially if it's abusive) for moderator attention and it will be dealt with.

---

> 1. It is just hard or impossible to predict if question is opinion based.

Sometimes, it certainly is, that's why we have procedures to reopen closed questions. The Politics question you mention has two pending reopen votes<sup>*</sup>. Otherwise, users with a lot more experience than me and you can often predict the nature of answers quite well. They simply *know* whether a question is going to work for the site or not.

> 2. It is unfriendly for especially new users who do not have bad intentions.

This is an unfortunate misconception, which admittedly can be hard to grow out of. We vote on the content, not on the user. Not everything fits into the Stack Exchange Q&A model.

> for him feedback that "it is opinion-based" was not clear enough (the same as for me often).

Sure. That's why there is a link in the close banner leading to [this Help Center article](/help/closed-questions) with tips specifically for opinion-based questions, which links to [another Help Center article](/help/reopen-questions) with even more tips.

> 3. It is difficult to reconcile with questions about ethics.

Agreed, some 'soft' topics are harder to formulate an objective question about than 'hard' topics like software development, technology or mathematics. But if we didn't, we would need a lot more moderation power to keep all the ensuing discussion under control. The main problem is that you can prove an objective statement is right or wrong; an opinion you can only agree/disagree with.

<sup>*: You don't see them yet because [you don't have enough reputation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).</sup>

Comment: Let's focus on third point - why is it OK for you to let community _falsely_ mark an question as opinion-based and punish askers rather than let askers to _falsely_ keep a question as not opinion-based and punish responders by expecting that _they_ will do extra work by showing that it is possible to answer the question based on facts. See that @VLAZ said above: _Does the question have a concrete factual answer? Then it's not opinion based_ - he shows that in fact it is all a matter of responders, not askers.

Comment: If it's not really opinion-based, it should be reopened and we have procedures for that (see my response to 1.)

Comment: Saying that, you are leaving this topic in a fog of black-box :(

Comment: ... which is (when it comes to specific questions) better answered at communities' own Meta sites. We are no Politics experts here.

Answer (score 0):

> there is no hard rules for when question will be marked as opinion-based

While there are no hard rules, there is e.g. [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), which gives some idea of when questions are too opinion-based. This is a combination of both how the question is written, and the answers it is likely to invite. Simply put:  **We can't tell users putting text in the answer box 'don't give us your opinion' if the questions they are writing their text under are likely inviting exactly that: Opinions.** So no, we should not switch from closing questions to only moderating their answers.

While there is a difference between posting on a main site and a meta site, because questions on meta (whether that be site-specific or here) are inherently going to be more opinion based, the standars I hold them to are the same as or heavily based on some of the standards in the blog post I linked:

- A good meta question invites answers that explain why something should be done, how you think something should be done.
- A good meta question invites answers that are longer and more substantial than just chiming in with a yes, no or other forms of (dis)agreement.
- Good meta questions have a constructive, fair and impartial tone.
- And, with a very few exceptions, a good meta question is more than just mindless fun/discussion. What is the purpose or goal of having a certain discussion, what is the goal we're all trying to achieve by giving our opinions?

If it's not meeting some or any of that, your meta question may be closed, it may receive downvotes (if it's not impartial, there will be votes for agree/disagree on meta sites too).

**With a big disclaimer that I'm not an 'native' to any of their communities, and as such their standards may differ from the ones I described above:** Looking specifically at the examples you posted, they didn't meet the criteria from the blog post I linked. The Politics.se question is still asking for opinions on whether something is a sufficient argument, not facts or experience, which is a big no-no. Your Stack Overflow Meta question isn't really 'impartial', and falls in the 'mindless fun' category for me. I don't see what you're trying to achieve by collecting these opinions.

Comment: Thanks! My intention is to write the questions which less likely be marked as opinion-based and closed / reopened / closed again as the one of my questions. And also to help people which have similar problem, optionally to show that the present system is bad as the community too often marks as opinion-based this what they don't like (see one of the comments about this in my question regarding making business with Russians by SE). _asking for opinions on whether something is a sufficient argument_ - thank you very much, that's helpful! Perhaps I will try later to edit this question again!

Comment: @gss Take the advice with you for your next questions, but be careful when editing existing ones, especially answered ones. If your edits invalidate existing answers, they will be rolled back (and your questions aren't the place to react to answers either). As for discussions the community doesn't like to see: I want to see *useful* discussions, ones that have goals. Other users/communities have different standards, and want to see any kind of discussion, including stuff about whether or not a company has a moral obligation, without even knowing the company's own viewpoint yet.

Comment: I was thinking about the discussion community doesn't like to see because _it could_ provide answers they won't like, because of their (i..e community) poiltical opinions / prejudices: [_They are being cast because people don't like questions accusing Stack Exchange of supporting "the bad guys_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376666/is-stack-exchange-network-making-business-with-russians-organizations-nowadays). I agree about usefulness, i.e. it is OK for me to judge the question in usefulness context, but not because of some political believes which somebody has.

Comment: Well, fair. I don't like questions accusing SE of supporting bad guys either, as those aren't 'constructive, fair and impartial in tone', which was one of my bullet points above.  What's jumping out more to me though: To me, it mostly seems like you are skipping dozen steps each time you ask a question (or write an answer). Here, you're asking for a new feature when the essential misunderstanding seems to be about what can make a question primarily opinion based on these sites. 1/2

Comment: On SO Meta, you're asking users whether they think SE should have a specific moral obligation, without first attempting to gather information on what SE thinks their moral obligation is/isn't, and why they are/aren't doing specific things. You've also written [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376658) on this site, and only after writing that asked [that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376666) soliciting data to back up the argument you made in said answer. Users here aren't blind, they notice stuff like that, they see that your question isn't 'impartial'. 2/2

Comment: In fact, if those users look even closer, they will see that all of your participation on Meta.SE, SO Meta *and* Politics.SE is somehow restricted or related to posts about the current war. You probably just have bad timing, but posts about hot-button topics like these are often some of the hardest to write and have the steepest learning curves. My last bit of advice would be to focus on getting a hang of the more subjective sites and meta sites through activity around more 'regular' topics, and just limiting yourself to 'watch and learn' for the more hot-button ones for a few rounds. 3/2

Comment: I really believe it would be better to change this on the system level, as described in my question. I still think that, well, marking question as opinion-based is often opinion-based :). There is no need to think I have bad intentions. Yes, I believe SE should do something regarding war, but I really try to be with this in line with the rules in this site, not against the site itself. No need to treat SE specially, i.e. look at my posts and instead of SE use any other company. Is it still look bad or not? If not, then it is something really wrong to downvote because of use of "SE".

Comment: I would add something more: I'm a part of SO and I'm ashamed of what SE is doing now. But you are right, all of this is really hard (regarding hot-button topics), thank you for advice :)