# How is Stack Exchange Inc dealing with current and future business with Russian entities?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, advertising, stack-overflow-for-teams, so-enterprise

I've been putting off asking this question for a while, but it came up in the comments for the question about [Stack Exchange Q&A access in Russia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376743/stack-exchange-qa-access-will-not-be-restricted-in-russia?noredirect=1&lq=1) and is worth addressing.

While I consider public Q&A a common good - Stack does rely on various products - advertising spaces (which is intrinsically tied with public Q&A) and commercial Q&A products such as teams and Stack Overflow Enterprise are sources of revenue. While the specific *organizations*  are something that I understand SE wouldn't share - What is SE's policy on current clients who are in Russia as well as future sign ups for teams, enterprise, advertising and other products?

How would support be for current customers in these situations - and I guess practically what would be the impact of the war on the commercial aspects of SE?

Comment: Oh, I really hope the comment section does not turn into another Reddit-like discussion... Good question, though. AFAIK,  Teams have been unavailable for Russians for a while, even before the war

Comment: Phew, found the post about Teams: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411099/11407695

Comment: This post was kinda thought out since... literally the war started, and I sat on it 2 days before I posted it. Yeah, as a moderator here, I am entirely aware of what kinda mess I could be stepping in

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Russia (Russian corporations) is not on the internally-approved list of countries that we do business with across any of our paid products, including the free self-serve version of Stack Overflow for Teams, which is not available to be licensed in the region.

Comment: Just curious, has this always been the case or is it a change as a result of recent events?

Comment: @Cerbrus As per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411099 , it was already in effect in August 2021 (possibly much earlier).

Comment: This approach preceded the war in Ukraine.

Comment: What is the reason for not including Russia in this internally-approved list of countries? Can we know which countries are in this list?

Comment: What factors are used to place or remove a country from your "internally-approved list"? Is it based on a defined rubric of political and economic freedom factors that produce a score, and a country must score above a threshold to be included? Is it based the inclusion of a country on specific sanctions lists (i.e. all countries are approved except ones that appear on one of the lists)? Do all managers get together and vote (e.g. "The motion to add Tonga to the list of approved countries passes 8-2.")?